# How do I customize a position for a leaflet-search bar beyond the default "topleft,topright,etc"

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am developing a map for an online game using Leaflet. I have the plugins "leaflet-search" and "easy-button".

I currently have multiple layers of markers attached to different toggle buttons (that toggle visibility of marker layers). When a user clicks a button to display a set of markers, i would like for a search bar to appear directly to the right of said clicked button.

```
    //SearchBar1
    var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: markersLayer,
        initial: false,
        zoom: 6,
        marker: false,
        minLength: 2,
        position: 'topleft', //would like to customize this position
        autoType: true,
        textErr: 'Boss not found',
        tipAutoSubmit: true,
        firstTipSubmit: true
    });
```

[[1]: https://i.gyazo.com/846004a6eeb8ec3a6a8bc3ad1c6a0db4.png "desired result"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoBB8.png)

Everything is working perfect other than the position of the search bar. The search bar position as far as I have found is limited to the default leaflet 'topright', 'topleft' etc positions. Is there a way to specify a location so that it appears 25px to the right of the clicked button?

Apologies if I'm doing anything wrong, first time using stackoverflow.